# Auto-complete file path on ESS R-mode

Tags: auto-complete-mode

I've got auto-complete package working for functions for *.R files, but now I'm struggling with auto-complete for file paths.

I've bound the "TAB" key to:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'ac-complete-filename)
```

And it does work after "/" symbol as suggested [here](http://auto-complete.org/doc/manual.html#ac-source-filename). However it works only on new line. As in:

```
/
```

And it does not work from within a function such as:

```
read.table("/...")
```

Placing pointer after "/" when anything precedes it does not do anything.
Any suggestions?

Update:

Changing binding to ess-mode instead of global fixed it. Why? No idea...

```
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'ac-complete-filename)
```

Comment: Could there have been a pre-existing key-binding for tab in ess-mode? That would have overridden the global key-binding.

Comment: ac-complete-filename is sort of conditional keybind, that works only after "/" symbol. I wonder how it interferes with other bindings? And after some more struggle with setting up auto-complete, I'm still far off my initial goal. Trying to mimic auto-complete feature as in RStudio. Otherwise switching to emacs will not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks. This solution also worked for me. Now, after typing the "/" symbol, auto complete brings up the file directories. Interestingly, when I'm in the R session within emacs, e.g. `iESS [R]`, file completion works using the standard emacs file completion, but `auto-complete` also works for functions (this works with or without `(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'ac-complete-filename)`. This seems to be the best of both worlds. It would be great if someone with a deeper knowledge of ESS could shed some light on how to get this formulation to work for `*.R` files as well.

Comment: ESS `r-mode` comes with file-name completion built-in. You shouldn't have to bind `ac-complete-filename` to anything, as by default ess modifies `completion-at-point-functions` to work as you want without further configuration. That is, tab completes R objects in code, and completes filenames inside strings, which is what you'd normally want.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone comes across this question; I was able to do this by essentially turning on tab completion from R as follows:

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "M-h") 'ac-quick-help)
;; Get tab completion in R script files
;; See this page here
;; https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2013-March/008719.html
;; Make sure that this is after the auto-complete package initialization
(setq  ess-tab-complete-in-script t)
```